# R sweep-equivalent with integer division

Tags: r

Is there a way to use `sweep(dataframe)` with integer division, or something that is equivalent to such?

This is a minimal example of `sweep` *not* using integer division - which I want to replace with integer division:

```
sweep(x = mtcars, MARGIN = 2, STATS = unlist(mtcars[1,]), FUN = '/')
```

Some limitations I need to stick to:

- I need to preserve the column names of the dataframe, as done in the example above.
- I cannot just use `round`, `floor`, `ceil`, or similar - it needs to be an equivalent of integer division (`floor` would have different effects on negative numbers than integer division).
- If possible, I'd prefer to not store any information in additional variables during this process.
- I'm dealing with a relatively large dataframe, so it could turn out that very slow solutions might not be an option here.

Does anyone know a way of achieving this in R?

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your input. How would you improve this question? In its current form it represents my POV/knowledge at the time of solving this problem.

Comment: @Roland Instead of just deleting your previous comment, but leaving the corresponding downvote: please provide constructive information on how you would *improve* the question. I'll definitely consider doing so, given some feedback. Seems a bit weird that I have to point this out here... thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass '%/%' as your function, that is integer division. See [arithmetic operator docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html).

```
sweep(x = mtcars, MARGIN = 2, STATS = unlist(mtcars[1,]), FUN = '%/%')
```

Comment: Nice, exactly the answer I was looking for! Thx!

Comment: I recommend using \``%/%`\` instead of `'%/%'` (that is, backticks). Using a character string here works but is semantically meaningless and the fact that R supports this is stupid.